# Add column with sheet name with Power Query?

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a power query that extracts all this information and sorts it into columns but I would like to add one that also states the sheet the value is pulled from. Here is my current code:

```
let
    Source = Query1(),
    #"Removed Top Rows" = Table.Skip(Source,2),
    #"Expanded Content" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Top Rows", "Content", {"Attribute", "Value"}, {"Content.Attribute", "Content.Value"}),
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Expanded Content", {"Content.Value"}),
    #"Removed Blank Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Removed Duplicates", each not List.IsEmpty(List.RemoveMatchingItems(Record.FieldValues(_), {"", null}))),
    #"Removed Errors" = Table.RemoveRowsWithErrors(#"Removed Blank Rows", {"Content.Value"}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Removed Errors",{{"Content.Value", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Extracted Text Range" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Sorted Rows", {{"Name", each Text.Middle(_, 1, 8), type text}})
in
    #"Extracted Text Range"
```

When I add a custom column with the function

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("c:\temp\test0001.xlsx")),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Kind] = "Sheet")),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Name"})
in
    #"Removed Other Columns"
```

it adds a column with the sheet names but it ends up duplicating every cell about 23 times. This is fine because I can remove duplicates, but once I do the sheet name column switches all cells to equal "1". How do I fix this?

[image: PQD]

[image: PQDSNs]

[image: PQDSNsRD]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with

```
let Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("c:\temp2\pp.xlsx")),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Kind] = "Sheet")),
List = List.Union(List.Transform(#"Filtered Rows"[Data], each Table.ColumnNames(_))),
#"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "Data", List,List)
in  #"Expanded Data"
```

then add your subsequent steps from there.  You dont want to go back and add it after all the steps are done